# In Hartl's Rails tutorial (Rails 5, section 8.2.3), why can an instance variable defined in a method be called without the @?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, instance-variables

I'm a newbie working my way through Hartl's Rails 5 tutorial when I came across this piece of confusing code listed below.  It looks like @current_user is being defined within a method as an instance variable, so that it may be used outside the method.  However, in the logged_in? method, no @ symbol is needed to call on it.  In fact, if I add rewrite logged_in? to use @current_user, it no longer works as intended!

```
module SessionsHelper

  # Logs in the given user.
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  # Returns the current logged-in user (if any).
  def current_user
    if session[:user_id]
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
    end
  end

  # Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end
end
```

When I try this in ruby, I'm unable to use an instance variable in this way.  The example I tried is below.  When I call method2, I get an error that isn't fixed until I add an @ symbol in front of var1.  Can anyone help me understand this?  Thanks!!

```
def method1
    @var1 = 2
    @var1
end

def method2
    @var1 == 2
end

puts method1
puts method2
```

Answer (score 0):

`current_user` is being defined as a method, and then inside the method, an instance variable `@current_user` is defined, which is only used inside the method.  The `logged_in?` method is calling the `current_user` method, it is not accessing the `@current_user` variable directly.  Note that in ruby, the `@`, `$`, or `@@` are actually part of the variable name, and are not *modifiers*.  Therefore, `current_user` and `@current_user` are not the same entity.